# Server 2012 R2 is not using my Server 2012 R2 License Server

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, licensing, rds

### First Question:

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 server that hosts my license server.  It is set up with two sets of licenses packs (a 5 user cal and a 10 user cal).

Currently on the first pack of 5, all 5 are used.  On the second pack of 10, 2 are used.  So I should have a few more seats available (per the management console).

For some reason my SQL server (also running Server 2012 R2) is giving me issues when more than two users try to log on.  It's like my MSSQL server will only allow two users to log on at a time.  Giving me the impression it's NOT trying to use the license server.

Everything is set up in the domain to use the license server and it looks like my other servers are using the license server with no issues.

> Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows
>   Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session
>   Host\Licensing\
>
> Use the specified Remote Desktop license servers - Enabled
>
> Set the Remote Desktop licensing mode - Enabled

Is there something on each server that should be done to utilize the license server?  Or is GPO on my domain the only thing I need to do?  Is there something I forgot to do on my SQL server that I might have done on my other server having no issues?

### Second question:

When I have 10 users on my domain logging on to multi servers does a ONE USER CAL license allow for a bunch of logins to different servers?  Or does ONE USER CAL license translate to once user/one server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For some reason my SQL server (also running Server 2012 R2) is giving me issues when more than two users try to log on. It's like my MSSQL server will only allow two users to log on at a time. Giving me the impression it's NOT trying to use the license server.

More than two sessions only applies if the server(s) have the Remote Desktop Session Host role installed.

Comment: That's what I was after!  Thanks.  I ended up adding the following Roles to my SQL server `Remote Desktop Services->Remote Desktop Connection Broker`, `Remote Desktop Services->Remote Desktop Session Host` as well as the following Features `Remote Server Administration Tools->Role Administration Tools->Remote Desktop Service Tools->Remote Desktop Licensing Diagnoser Tools`.  Then a reboot is required.

Answer (score 1):

*For your second question;* as Greg answer you the first question.

> When I have 10 users on my domain logging on to multi servers does a
>   ONE USER CAL license allow for a bunch of logins to different servers?
>   Or does ONE USER CAL license translate to once user/one server.

Yes for user CAL, it allow a user to use any server resources under that version of OS (2012R2). (except SQL or RDS)

You miss the fact, do you have **RDS-User CAL** too ? Those would allow a user to login to your RDP server. You need both of those CAL type to cover your RDP server use. (and the same exercise apply to your SQL server, do you have CAL for it ?)

*As a reminder to recognize them, a normal user cal cost like 20$, while a RDS-user CAL more like around 200$.*